# Writing Arabic chars in Android

Tags: android, arabic

This is the code I used 
but every time I excute it force to stop.
note that I use it on android 2.1

```
package com.arb;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class arabi extends Activity
{
AssetManager arabi_font;

TextView tx;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
tx=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tt);

try{

arabi_font.open("DejaVuSans.ttf");

//DejaVuSans.ttf font file

tx.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(arabi_font,"DejaVuSans.ttf"));
tx.setText("\uFEB3\uFE92\uFE98\uFE94");
}


catch(Exception ex){
} 


}
}
```

Comment: And... can you post the log of you app?

Comment: what do you mean by the log of my app

Comment: `adb shell logcat > file`. At least on Linux :)

Comment: I'm not using linux how I can provid it from eclipse

Comment: You can find your solution [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've just recode several lines, I belive it's working...

```
try{

   //arabi_font.open("DejaVuSans.ttf");

   //DejaVuSans.ttf font file

   tx.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"DejaVuSans.ttf"));
   tx.setText("\uFEB3\uFE92\uFE98\uFE94");
}
catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: the complete code is at http://blog.kerul.net/2010/12/connected-arabic-characters-for-android.html . thanx to Amr Gawish