# Android Arabic text alignment

Tags: android, arabic

I use class from [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android) to show Arabic text. In Android 2.1 - 2.3 text located in the left side, so I use android:gravity="right", but in Android 3.0+ Arabic text has automatically alignment in right side and if I use android:gravity="right" in will be alignment in the left side. How can I make the text to be aligned with the same in different Android versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create different versions of the layouts for different API versions.

As you can read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html you can have say the normal folder (`/res/layout/`) with the layout for old devices and then another one for the ones that support it: `/res/layout-11/`

The layout inside `layout-v11` will only be applied on devices with android 3.0 and over.

Hope it helps.
(UPD: API level changed to 11)

**UPDATE**

On Android 4.2 This is a native feature :)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: [Ustav](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1294952/ustav) [points out](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/228384) that Android 3.0 is [API level 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) not 10.