# Android Emulator Arabic Support

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, arabic

I'm facing an issue here in my emulator (2.2 , 2.33). My problem is that i can't write any arabic letters in my edittexts even when i set the input language under the Language settings into arabic and set my windows language to arabic , The emulator still write in english . i need it so badly to fill my database to be ready for publishing. Your answer is highly appreciated !!

Comment: Have a look at this post, it may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813

Comment: Thanks for the link , But i think i don't care about viewing the Arabic letters properly in the emulator. i just need to write :))

Answer (score 3):

Ok, got your question better now.  The problem is that Android default keyboard simply does not support Arabic input.  You will NOT be able to input Arabic characters with the default Android keyboard.  The only way to ago around it is to install a custom keyboard.

It's not too difficult, but not exactly straight forward, because you cannot access Market (sorry, Google Play) from the emulator.  Here's what you need to do.

1. On an actual phone install a keyboard that supports Arabic input - and the corresponding Arabic expansion pack.  I suggest [AnysoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tZW5ueS5hbmRyb2lkLmFueXNvZnRrZXlib2FyZCJd) and its [Arabic pack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.arabic&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5hbnlzb2Z0a2V5Ym9hcmQubGFuZ3VhZ2VwYWNrLmFyYWJpYyJd)
2. Connect your phone to your PC with a USB cable and copy the .apk files for the keyboard and the expansion pack to your PC.  You'll need to use `adb pull` command for that: `adb -d pull /data/app/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.apk` and `adb -d pull /data/app/com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.arabic.apk`
3. (You can disconnect your phone now).  Start the emulator and install these .apk files onto the emulator:  `adb -e intall com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.apk` and `adb -e install com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.arabic.apk`
4. Now in the emulator navigate to "Settings -> Language & and Keyboard settings", remove the checkmarks next to all devices, then scroll down to "AnySoftKeyboard" and place the checkmark next to it (press "OK" on the dialog).  Just below it, select "AnySoftKeyboard Settings" and then "Keyboards".  Make sure "English" and "Arabic" are both checked - and exit settings.
5. Finally, you can start your application, select your edit text - the keyboard will pop-up - it will look different from the one you are used to.  Click the "-> ABC ->" button at the top right corner of the keyboard to switch the language.  Provided you have Arabic font installed, you should be able to input Arabic characters now.

Good luck!  (Note that I do not know Arabic language at all, so the characters in the screenshot are the result of my random tapping of the keys on the keyboard to demonstrate the input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a try and feed back to you :))

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's native support for Arabic text till Honeycomb (3.0). But I've read if you make use of some Arabic fonts then it can be achieved. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813)

Comment: Thanks for your answer BUT I've downloaded 3.2 SDK and the emulator can read arabic fine but there is no Arabic input support in the Language settings . any other clues?