# Textview is Messing up with Arabic Letters

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, arabic

i am develop an android application that let the user to insert some information in Edit text (in Arabic letters) like user name, and showing his inserted information in another Activity by using textView

But, when i run my application and insert the name in arabic letters and show it in second activity , it missed up !!

i do not know how to let the text View order with arabic letters

Any Help will really appreciate it

This is my XML code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:padding="5dp" >

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel3"
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_x="188dp"
        android:layout_y="437dp"

        android:text="إلغاء"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send3"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_x="26dp"
        android:layout_y="436dp"

        android:text="إرسال"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stoppingalram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_x="114dp"
        android:layout_y="438dp"
        android:text="إلغاء" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="548dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_x="-120dp"
        android:layout_y="8dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_x="120dp"
        android:layout_y="77dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvmoreinfoReport"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_x="156dp"
        android:layout_y="372dp"
        android:text="لا شئ"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvclothesReport"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_x="138dp"
        android:layout_y="321dp"
        android:text="فستان أحمر"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtimeReport"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_x="159dp"
        android:layout_y="282dp"
        android:text="ساعة ١"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvgenderReport"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_x="177dp"
        android:layout_y="207dp"
        android:text="أنثى"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvageReport"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="174dp"
        android:layout_y="236dp"
        android:text="سنة ٩"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvcasenameReport"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_x="145dp"
        android:layout_y="174dp"
        android:text="محمد عبدالله"
        />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried placing this text in \u notation ?

Comment: and try to check your file encoding in some text editor, it must be utf-8

Comment: @xitx yes i put it as utf 8 but can where should i put \u ?

Comment: this can be also problem with fonts see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813 answer in comments if it helped you

Comment: @xitx so how can i convert my whole application to 3.x !! i almost finish my app !!! should i rebuild my app again ? if no, how can i convert to 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i click the right click Button and change to 4.0.3 and press OK then it is Done :)
2.1 it does not support Arabic,  2.3 not Fully support Arabic , 3.x is support fully Arabic