# Android print arabic words

Tags: android, arabic, android-2.2-froyo

i want to build client/server application, the client is android (2.2) application, and the server is tomcat Java server ,IDE is Eclips

i want to send arabic data from server to client using servlet, i found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android)
and it is very helpful ,but my problem is that when i used this:

```
info.setText(Farsi.Convert("وليم"));
```

it works good and print that arabic word, but when i print the arabic data comes from the server like this:

```
info.setText(Farsi.Convert(results[0]));
```

it prints strange english word
so maybe the problem is on sending data from server to client, or in another place?

#### things may be helpful to know the problem

1. i can print the arabic data on console on server and it works good
2. the data is coming from mysql and the field is `utf8_unicode_ci`
3. i send the data from  server to client using servlet like this:`response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");response.setHeader("Info", word);`

please any help!! ,because this application is my graduation project and i have to support arabic.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

My point - you shouldn't use headers for arabic words, use response **body** instead.

The reason that is hidden here - by default java.lang.String constructors using default system encoding, and it could be NOT UTF-8 encoding. You should create string from byte arrays specifying UTF-8 encoding manually, but this is impossible when using headers, AFAIK.