# Why Arabic characters don't appear in emulator with android 2.2

Tags: java, android, encoding, arabic

I have used the example in this [link](http://mdictionary.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/connected-arabic-characters-for-android-apps/) and it displayed arabic on android 2.3 well, but in android 2.2 nothing appeared , why ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Arabic wasn't supported until after 2.2

2.3 introduced a bunch of new language support [features](http://www.androidcentral.com/gingerbread-gets-arabic-slew-other-new-languages).

Comment: Please check the example attached.

Comment: I did look at your example. but that still doesn't change the fact that android could not display arabic characters correctly until after 2.2

Comment: @Recursed Man, the emulator in the example is 2.2 , the example is reshaping the Arabic characters by displaying the it's Unicode correctly .