# Is Farsi language available on Android?

Tags: android, localization, persian, farsi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android)

I am considering localizing my Android app to Farsi (Iran) where it appears to be getting some downloads. But I am wondering if Farsi is even supported by Android handsets?

IE, have people in Iran set their phone language to Farsi?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android - has a top answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/30225 that, though about Arabic - seems to contain some Farsi support/Classes. And some simple searches lead to lots of Farsi apps like readers, dictionaries, fonts, and keyboards for android. Sorry can't help anymore.

Comment: Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). There is a complete answer about Farsi support in different versions of Android.

Comment: if you can write and read something like SMS in farsi in your phone you can use directly farsi in your application. if not use @softwareisfun post.

Comment: What about 2.3.0 - 2.3.7? does android provide full support there?

Comment: same as Android 2.2 (has Arabic font but does not show your word correctly.) I posted the milestones where the API changes

Comment: thanks for the link. i created my farsi resources in _res-fa-v12/strings.xml_ so its honeycomb+ compatible and doesn't need any special coding. devices below honeycomb see english even if language is set to farsi.

Comment: i ended up putting the resources in _res/values-fa-v12/strings.xml_ to avoid special coding.