# Arabic Text Issue In Android

Tags: android

I am working on an application that will work on Android `WebView`. I enabled the selection and copy for this view. In some devices that support Arabic, When I paste the copied text from `WebView` in any `EditText` view, It shows me the **reserve text**. but In some cases it shows me the **correct form**.

Could any one please help me to show in correct form in all devices ? :-/

I have red all threads that depend on supporting Arabic and Farsi Text, but I can not reach my purpose.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your copied text to [FarsiLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813). It will analyses your text letters and justify them according to their possible 4 states (Initial, Middle, End, Isolated) :

Initial like 'ن' in 'نازک'
Middle like 'ن' in 'هنر'
End like 'ن' in 'وطن'
Isolated like 'ن' in 'ایران'

Answer (score 0):

Android has Added support for RTL in Native widgets(i.e TextView , EditText) . so if u run the app onward 4.2 u will get RTL feature automatically ,

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

You can create different versions of the layouts for different API versions.

As you can read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html you can have say the normal folder (/res/layout/) with the layout for old devices and then another one for the ones that support it: /res/layout-11/

The layout inside layout-v11 will only be applied on devices with android 3.0 and over.