# How to join urdu words in android?

Tags: android, join, words

I want to write a plugin for SMS and Textview, Edittext and other applications to join urdu words in android. How can I do this?

I'v read hook does not work on android. Is there any solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android has built in support for rendering connected Arabic characters available from version 3.0 and above , below Android 3.0 the characters will appear broken , You may consider looking at [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 

I posted there a link ArabicReshaper that is working fine when I create an app for a firmware but I want to include the script in a firmware for joining words of sms and browser aaps to recompile gingerbread ROM. 

Which file will I have to edit? 

Thanks
also recommend me a book for android firmware development pls.

Comment: this is a good tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0 that will guide you towards step by step creation of custom Andriod ROM. I could not understand when you say about editing the file for RO M creation , maybe if you could explain more that might help me understand your point.

Comment: Yesterday I downloaded 2.3.5 firmware source code.
In the source code Which file I have to edit for joining words?
thanks.