# Weird Action with database query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a query that selects Person Name from DB based on value selected in Spinner ,the problem is when the selected item from spinner is English query works and app works great but when the selected item from Spinner is Farsi then app crashes. can someone help me?

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_expert);
String selectedItemFromSpin = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT PName FROM tbl_staff WHERE PMajor LIKE '%" + selectedItemFromSpin  + "%'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it. 
to get Arabic Type or Farsi Type texts to work I needed to use a class that is called FARSI and it had a method that reversed Farsi to Unicode. I used code of a user named "breceivedmail" ,thanks to him.

Solution:

```
Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT PName FROM tbl_staff WHERE PMajor LIKE '%" + Farsi.ConvertToRealFarsi(selectedItemFromSpin)  + "%'", null);
```

His code is in this address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/1290467