# Location of function to Support RTL in android

Tags: android, right-to-left, persian

Support of Right-To-Left Languages added to android since version 3.0
and problems like what i mentioned in:
[Dipaly farsi text in android webview (for phones not supporting farsi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855875/dipaly-farsi-text-in-android-webview-for-phones-not-supporting-farsi) are resolved in 3.0+ version. Meanwhile vendors implemented API support in their kernels for versions prior to 3.0.

I want to know where can i locate function for Right To Left support in android source code in order to import them in applications for version 2.x?