# how to display arabic letters correctly in android by using phonegap?

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making an android app in phonegap, It contains arabic and english text. I am also using arabic font, and changing fonts is working fine, in web browser the arabic text looks fine but in android device "HTC One V" that i am using for testing is not displayed as it should be, the file is saved in UTF-8 .  Can any one please tell me how can I display Arabic text properly in phonegap. Thanks

بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيم

```
 <li class="arabic">ٱللَّهُ لَآ إِلَـٰهَ إِلَّا هُوَ ٱلۡحَىُّ ٱلۡقَيُّومُۚ لَا تَأۡخُذُهُ ۥ سِنَةٌ۬ وَلَا نَوۡمٌ۬ۚ لَّهُ ۥ مَا فِى ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٲتِ وَمَا فِى ٱلۡأَرۡضِۗ مَن ذَا ٱلَّذِى يَشۡفَعُ عِندَهُ ۥۤ إِلَّا بِإِذۡنِهِۦۚ يَعۡلَمُ مَا بَيۡنَ أَيۡدِيهِمۡ وَمَا خَلۡفَهُمۡۖ وَلَا يُحِيطُونَ بِشَىۡءٍ۬  مِنْ عِلۡمِهِۦۤ إِلَّا بِمَا شَآءَۚ وَسِعَ كُرۡسِيُّهُ     ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٲتِ وَٱلۡأَرۡضَۖ وَلَا يَـُٔودُهُ ۥ حِفۡظُهُمَاۚ وَهُوَ ٱلۡعَلِىُّ ٱلۡعَظِيمُ <span class="ui-li-count">١</span></li>

 </ul>
and here is my css for arabic font
/*custom arabic fornt*/
@font-face {  
font-family: "customfont";  
src: url(../../../fonts/ar-Othmani.ttf) format("truetype");      

} 

.arabic {  
margin: 0;  
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /*prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold*/ 
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-user-select: none;    /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */

 font-family: "customfont" !important;  
 font-size:25px; 
 font-weight: normal !important;  
 }
```

Comment: that's related to each android os in your mobile.

Comment: i think there must be a solution to handle it through phonegap for different android devices...

Comment: it's a commune bug for android OS ( < 2.0.3), try to test it on new android OS, it will work fine ;)

Comment: but other apps containing arabic text are running perfectly on the same android OS.....

Comment: there is a solution on this [link] link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android?lq=1 for android devices to support arabic text but i dont know how can i use them on phonegap?

Comment: Which version of Cordova you're using?

Comment: @Evandro I am using cordova 2.9.0

Comment: are you able to solve your issue??

Comment: @Amir Saif Did you solve the problem?