# Farsi edit Text word not connected.how to show proper display?

Tags: java, android

I am developing application for android which have custom keyboard for RTL(Right to left) language. I designed keyboard. My problem is how to connect farsi or arabic characters. I tried this link

[How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813)

It shows farsi text well but failded on editbox. Please tell me how can I connect words.

My xml is:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

And edit text box code is:

```
edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        typeface = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);
        edittxt.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Words show in editbox SEPARATELY as داس ک

Pleae tell me how to connect words in edit textbox?

Comment: whats your android version?

Comment: i am testing on emulator.i am developing for honeycomb and above.but in edit box words are separated.:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android

Comment: sir my problem is for EditTexBox not for Textview. In textview it is pretty good.let me show my textbox and EditText.
 my textview its show good everything
typeface = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);
 txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
 txtView.setText(Farsi.Convert("سلام"));
 txtView.setTypeface(typeface);     problem with edittextbox    code is   edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        typeface = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);
        edittxt.setTypeface(typeface);

Comment: @wasqas could you please tell me any other solution