# How to show Arabic text on TextView on Android?

Tags: android, textview, arabic

In android Textview arabic text is not displaying properly it is breaking a word into alphabets. Is there any library or another way to resolve this issue?

Comment: This issue is fixed in Android 4. 
Which version of Android are you using?
Which version of emulator are you using?

Comment: well Ali,i checked it at 3.
and for OS less then 4 what i have to do?

Comment: Find a good reshaper library. Before adding text to Views, convert text with reshaper.

Comment: OK, by the way i am checking it at 4.2 it has some issue still it is displaying لوحة المفاتيح العربي like that ل وح ة ال م ف ات ي ح ال ع رب ي

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Farsi Class to do this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class Farsi {

    public static boolean isFarsiConversionNeeded = true;

    private final static String szLamAndAlef = Character
            .toString((char) 0xfedf)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam + Alef

    private final static String szLamStickAndAlef = Character
            .toString((char) 0xfee0)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                    // Alef

    private final static String szLa = Character.toString((char) 0xfefb); // La
    private final static String szLaStick = Character.toString((char) 0xfefc); // La
                                                                                // (Sticky!!!)

    private final static String szLamAndAlefWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0xe1)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam + Alef

    private final static String szLamStickAndAlefWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0x90)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                // Alef

    private final static String szLaWoosim = Character.toString((char) 0xd9); // La
    private final static String szLaStickWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0xd9); // La

    // (Sticky!!!)

    private static final class struc {
        public char character;
        public char endGlyph;
        public char iniGlyph;
        public char midGlyph;
        public char isoGlyph;

        public struc(char Character, char EndGlyph, char IniGlyph,
                char MidGlyph, char IsoGlyph) {
            character = Character;
            endGlyph = EndGlyph;
            iniGlyph = IniGlyph;
            midGlyph = MidGlyph;
            isoGlyph = IsoGlyph;
        }
    }

    static struc[] arrStruc = {
            new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab,
                    (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab),
            new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9,
                    (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9),
            new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0xfe9e, (char) 0xfe9f,
                    (char) 0xfea0, (char) 0xfe9d),
            new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0xfea2, (char) 0xfea3,
                    (char) 0xfea4, (char) 0xfea1),
            new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0xfea6, (char) 0xfea7,
                    (char) 0xfea8, (char) 0xfea5),
            new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xfeea, (char) 0xfeeb,
                    (char) 0xfeec, (char) 0xfee9),
            new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xfeca, (char) 0xfecb,
                    (char) 0xfecc, (char) 0xfec9),
            new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xfece, (char) 0xfecf,
                    (char) 0xfed0, (char) 0xfecd),
            new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xfed2, (char) 0xfed3,
                    (char) 0xfed4, (char) 0xfed1),
            new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xfed6, (char) 0xfed7,
                    (char) 0xfed8, (char) 0xfed5),
            new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xfe9a, (char) 0xfe9b,
                    (char) 0xfe9c, (char) 0xfe99),
            new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xfeba, (char) 0xfebb,
                    (char) 0xfebc, (char) 0xfeb9),
            new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xfebe, (char) 0xfebf,
                    (char) 0xfec0, (char) 0xfebd),
            new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xfec2, (char) 0xfec3,
                    (char) 0xfec4, (char) 0xfec1),
            new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xfeda, (char) 0xfedb,
                    (char) 0xfedc, (char) 0xfed9),
            new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xfee2, (char) 0xfee3,
                    (char) 0xfee4, (char) 0xfee1),
            new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xfee6, (char) 0xfee7,
                    (char) 0xfee8, (char) 0xfee5),
            new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xfe96, (char) 0xfe97,
                    (char) 0xfe98, (char) 0xfe95),
            new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d,
                    (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d),
            new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xfede, (char) 0xfedf,
                    (char) 0xfee0, (char) 0xfedd),
            new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xfe90, (char) 0xfe91,
                    (char) 0xfe92, (char) 0xfe8f),
            new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xfef2, (char) 0xfef3,
                    (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfef1),
            new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xfeb2, (char) 0xfeb3,
                    (char) 0xfeb4, (char) 0xfeb1),
            new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xfeb6, (char) 0xfeb7,
                    (char) 0xfeb8, (char) 0xfeb5),
            new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xfec6, (char) 0xfec7,
                    (char) 0xfec8, (char) 0xfec5),
            new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf,
                    (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf),
            new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed,
                    (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed),
            new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xfe94, (char) 0xfe93,
                    (char) 0xfe93, (char) 0xfe93),
            new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef,
                    (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef),
            new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead,
                    (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead),
            new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85,
                    (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85),
            new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80,
                    (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80),
            new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xfe8a, (char) 0xfe8b,
                    (char) 0xfe8c, (char) 0xfe89),
            new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83,
                    (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83),
            new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81,
                    (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81),
            new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87,
                    (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87),
            new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xfb57, (char) 0xfb58,
                    (char) 0xfb59, (char) 0xfb56), // peh
            new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0xfb7b, (char) 0xfb7c,
                    (char) 0xfb7d, (char) 0xfb7a), // cheh
            new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a,
                    (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a), // jeh
            new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xfb8f, (char) 0xfb90,
                    (char) 0xfb91, (char) 0xfb8e), // keheh
            new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xfb93, (char) 0xfb94,
                    (char) 0xfb95, (char) 0xfb92), // gaf
            // new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfbfe,
            // (char) 0xfbff, (char) 0xfbfc), // Farsi yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfef3,
                    (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfbfc), // Arabic yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4,
                    (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4) // heh with yeh
    };

    static struc[] arrStrucWoosim = {
            new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xb5, (char) 0x82, (char) 0xb5,
                    (char) 0x82),
            new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xb4, (char) 0x81, (char) 0xb4,
                    (char) 0x81),
            new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                    (char) 0xbf),
            new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0x9c, (char) 0xb2, (char) 0xfa,
                    (char) 0xc0),
            new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0x9d, (char) 0xb3, (char) 0xfe,
                    (char) 0xc1),
            new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                    (char) 0xd5),
            new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xc9, (char) 0xd3, (char) 0x8b,
                    (char) 0xa4),
            new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xca, (char) 0xdd, (char) 0x8c,
                    (char) 0xa5),
            new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xa6, (char) 0xde, (char) 0x8d,
                    (char) 0xcc),
            new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xa7, (char) 0xdf, (char) 0x8e,
                    (char) 0xce),
            new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                    (char) 0x99),
            new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xc4, (char) 0xc8, (char) 0x87,
                    (char) 0xa0),
            new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xc5, (char) 0xcb, (char) 0x88,
                    (char) 0xa1),
            new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xc6, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                    (char) 0xa2),
            new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8),
            new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xd2, (char) 0xe2, (char) 0x91,
                    (char) 0xaa),
            new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xd4, (char) 0xe3, (char) 0x92,
                    (char) 0xab),
            new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                    (char) 0x99),
            new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xbb, (char) 0x80, (char) 0xbb,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xd1, (char) 0xe1, (char) 0x90,
                    (char) 0xa9),
            new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                    (char) 0x98),
            new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc),
            new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xc2, (char) 0xb8, (char) 0xb8,
                    (char) 0x9e),
            new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xc3, (char) 0xb9, (char) 0xb9,
                    (char) 0x9f),
            new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xc7, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                    (char) 0xc7),
            new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                    (char) 0xb7),
            new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94,
                    (char) 0x94),
            new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda,
                    (char) 0xda),
            new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc),
            new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6,
                    (char) 0xb6),
            new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7,
                    (char) 0xe7),
            new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba,
                    (char) 0xba),
            new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xd7, (char) 0xe8, (char) 0x97,
                    (char) 0xd7),
            new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                    (char) 0x98), // peh
            new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                    (char) 0xbf), // cheh
            new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                    (char) 0xb7), // jeh
            new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8), // keheh
            new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8), // gaf
            new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc), // yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                    (char) 0xd5) // heh with yeh
    };

    private static final int N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS = 43;

    private static final String ArabicReverse(String s) {
        try {
            String Out = "", rev;
            s = MakeReverse(s);
            char[] chs = new char[s.length()];
            chs = s.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < s.length()) {
                if ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9')) // isDigit(s[i]) ?
                {
                    rev = "";
                    while (i < s.length()
                            && ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9') || chs[i] == '/')) // isDigit(s[i])
                                                                                    // ?
                    {
                        rev = rev + chs[i];
                        ++i;
                    }
                    rev = MakeReverse(rev);
                    Out = Out + rev;
                } else {
                    Out = Out + chs[i];
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            s = Out;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // throw new Exception(
            // "An exception has occurred in ArabicReverse function.\\n"
            // + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static final boolean isFromTheSet1(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
        char[] theSet1 = new char[] { (char) 0x62c, (char) 0x62d, (char) 0x62e,
                (char) 0x647, (char) 0x639, (char) 0x63a, (char) 0x641,
                (char) 0x642, (char) 0x62b, (char) 0x635, (char) 0x636,
                (char) 0x637, (char) 0x643, (char) 0x645, (char) 0x646,
                (char) 0x62a, (char) 0x644, (char) 0x628, (char) 0x64a,
                (char) 0x633, (char) 0x634, (char) 0x638, (char) 0x67e,
                (char) 0x686, (char) 0x6a9, (char) 0x6af, (char) 0x6cc,
                (char) 0x626 };
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 28) {
            if (ch == theSet1[i])
                return true;
            ++i;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static final boolean isFromTheSet2(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
        char[] theSet2 = new char[] { (char) 0x627, (char) 0x623, (char) 0x625,
                (char) 0x622, (char) 0x62f, (char) 0x630, (char) 0x631,
                (char) 0x632, (char) 0x648, (char) 0x624, (char) 0x629,
                (char) 0x649, (char) 0x698, (char) 0x6c0 };
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 14) {
            if (ch == theSet2[i])
                return true;
            ++i;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static final String MakeReverse(String text) {
        String Result = "";
        char[] Ctext = new char[text.length()];
        Ctext = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = (text.length()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Result += Ctext[i];
        }
        return Result;
    }

    public static final String ConvertBackToRealFarsi(String In) {

        if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
            return In;
        }

        String strOut = "";
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
        chIn = In.toCharArray();

        for (i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (j = 0; j < arrStruc.length; j++) {
                if (chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].midGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].iniGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].endGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].isoGlyph) {
                    strBuilder.append(arrStruc[j].character);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                strBuilder.append(chIn[i]);
        }

        strOut = strBuilder.toString();
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLa, "لا");
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLaStick, "لا");

        return strOut;
    }

    public static final String Convert(String In) {

        if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
            return In;
        }

        if (In == null) {
            return "";
        }

        boolean linkBefore, linkAfter;
        String Out = In;
        char[] chOut = new char[Out.length()];
        chOut = Out.toCharArray();
        char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
        chIn = In.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
            /* WCHAR */
            char ch = chIn[i];
            if ((ch >= (char) 0x0621 && ch <= (char) 0x064a)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x067e) || (ch == (char) 0x0686)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x0698) || (ch == (char) 0x06a9)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06af) || (ch == (char) 0x06cc)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06c0)) // is a Farsi character?
            {
                int idx = 0;
                while (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (arrStruc[idx].character == chIn[i])
                        break;
                    ++idx;
                }

                if (i == In.length() - 1)
                    linkAfter = false;
                else
                    linkAfter = (isFromTheSet1(chIn[i + 1]) || isFromTheSet2(chIn[i + 1]));
                if (i == 0)
                    linkBefore = false;
                else
                    linkBefore = isFromTheSet1(chIn[i - 1]);
                if (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].midGlyph;
                    if (linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].endGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].iniGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].isoGlyph;
                } else {
                    chOut[i] = chIn[i];
                }
            } else {
                chOut[i] = chIn[i];
            }
        }
        Out = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < chOut.length; j++)
            Out += chOut[j];
        // Out = ArabicReverse(Out);

        Out = Out.replace((char) 0x200c, ' '); // Change NO SPACE to SPACE

        Out = Out.replace(szLamAndAlef, szLa); // Join 'Lam' and 'Alef' and
                                                // make 'La'
        Out = Out.replace(szLamStickAndAlef, szLaStick); // Join 'Lam Stick'
                                                            // and 'Alef'
                                                            // and make 'La
                                                            // Stick'

        return reorderWords(Out);

    }

    private final static String reorderWords(String strIn)
    {

        final int ST_RTL = 0;
        final int ST_LTR = 1;

        String strOut = "";
        String prevWord = "";
        int state = ST_RTL;
        char[] arr = strIn.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (charIsLTR(arr[i]) && state != ST_LTR)
            {
                // state changed to LTR
                state = ST_LTR;
                strOut = prevWord + strOut;
                prevWord = "";
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            else if (charIsRTL(arr[i]) && state != ST_RTL)
            {
                // state changed to RTL
                state = ST_RTL;
                strOut = prevWord + strOut;
                prevWord = "";
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                // state is not changed
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            i++;
        }

        strOut = prevWord + strOut;

        return strOut;

    }

    private final static boolean charIsLTR(char ch)
    {
        return (ch >= (char) 65 & ch <= (char) 122)
                |
                Character.isDigit(ch);
    }

    private final static boolean charIsRTL(char ch)
    {
        return ch >= (char) 0x0621;
    }   

    private static Typeface typeface;

public static final Typeface GetFarsiFont(Context context) {
        if (typeface == null) {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    // "DroidSansFallback.ttf");
                    "TAHOMA.TTF");
        }
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

and for calling that:

```
Typeface tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);
MyTextView.setTypeface(tf);
MyTextView.setText(Farsi.Convert("سلام"));
```

you need TAHOMA.TTF" in assets folder too

for more info see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android)

if you don't want add font to your application just use

```
MyTextView.setText(Farsi.Convert("سلام"));
```

Comment: whats your mean about `but not for this arabic text`

Comment: Thanks Shayan pourvatan :)

Comment: but it will not work for quranic arabic like this
قُلِ اللَّهُمَّ مَالِكَ الْمُلْكِ تُؤْتِي الْمُلْكَ مَنْ تَشَاءُ وَتَنْزِعُ الْمُلْكَ مِمَّنْ تَشَاءُ وَتُعِزُّ مَنْ تَشَاءُ وَتُذِلُّ مَنْ تَشَاءُ ۖ بِيَدِكَ الْخَيْرُ ۖ إِنَّكَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ
any solution for it?