# Farsi app_name doesn't show correctly in android 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android, character, arabic, right-to-left, farsi

I'm new to android and I'm developing an app in Farsi.

Farsi characters are not shown correctly in android 2.2 and 2.3. The characters are shown separately 
This link solves the problem for the code

[How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813)

But I don't know how to fix the problem in android manifest.xml for the app name.
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: can i ask you why you insist on supporting those two old versions?
there are a few phones even in iran that run on those versions. instead of solving this issue i suggest you put your minSDKVersion on API 11 or higher.

Comment: I ended up doing so :)

Comment: you've done the right thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Farsi class introduced in that link and generate your application name and store it in a file. Then open that file and copy the generated text and paste it in `manifest.xml`.

Also you can generate your app name in your android code and get it in debug mode, copy it and paste in `manifest.xml`.

Comment: Then I will have search issues cause users cannot search properly in Android Markets. But as it seems what u say i the only solution for one who insists on it (+1). I finally ended up using English name. Tnx 4 your reply.