# How to use not supported language in android

Tags: android

Unfortunately Persian language not supported in API level lower than 11, And it's not display in the correct format. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this is going to be complicated. LTR languages display is supported on android 10-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use something that is not supported in that API. My suggestion would be to increase your minimum target API to 11. There is no way of getting around such a thing.

As for it not displaying it correctly, Abdallah's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) answers that question.

Relevant Information from the Answer:

> 1) At first add "TAHOMA.TTF" in assets folder
>
> 2) use the following class to get the font and converting your Arabic
>   or Farsi text to a good form for showing in your activities.

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class Farsi {

    public static boolean isFarsiConversionNeeded = true;

    private final static String szLamAndAlef = Character
            .toString((char) 0xfedf)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam + Alef

    private final static String szLamStickAndAlef = Character
            .toString((char) 0xfee0)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                    // Alef

    private final static String szLa = Character.toString((char) 0xfefb); // La
    private final static String szLaStick = Character.toString((char) 0xfefc); // La
                                                                                // (Sticky!!!)

    private final static String szLamAndAlefWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0xe1)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam + Alef

    private final static String szLamStickAndAlefWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0x90)
            + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                // Alef

    private final static String szLaWoosim = Character.toString((char) 0xd9); // La
    private final static String szLaStickWoosim = Character
            .toString((char) 0xd9); // La

    // (Sticky!!!)

    private static final class struc {
        public char character;
        public char endGlyph;
        public char iniGlyph;
        public char midGlyph;
        public char isoGlyph;

        public struc(char Character, char EndGlyph, char IniGlyph,
                char MidGlyph, char IsoGlyph) {
            character = Character;
            endGlyph = EndGlyph;
            iniGlyph = IniGlyph;
            midGlyph = MidGlyph;
            isoGlyph = IsoGlyph;
        }
    }

    static struc[] arrStruc = {
            new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab,
                    (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab),
            new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9,
                    (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9),
            new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0xfe9e, (char) 0xfe9f,
                    (char) 0xfea0, (char) 0xfe9d),
            new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0xfea2, (char) 0xfea3,
                    (char) 0xfea4, (char) 0xfea1),
            new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0xfea6, (char) 0xfea7,
                    (char) 0xfea8, (char) 0xfea5),
            new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xfeea, (char) 0xfeeb,
                    (char) 0xfeec, (char) 0xfee9),
            new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xfeca, (char) 0xfecb,
                    (char) 0xfecc, (char) 0xfec9),
            new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xfece, (char) 0xfecf,
                    (char) 0xfed0, (char) 0xfecd),
            new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xfed2, (char) 0xfed3,
                    (char) 0xfed4, (char) 0xfed1),
            new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xfed6, (char) 0xfed7,
                    (char) 0xfed8, (char) 0xfed5),
            new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xfe9a, (char) 0xfe9b,
                    (char) 0xfe9c, (char) 0xfe99),
            new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xfeba, (char) 0xfebb,
                    (char) 0xfebc, (char) 0xfeb9),
            new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xfebe, (char) 0xfebf,
                    (char) 0xfec0, (char) 0xfebd),
            new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xfec2, (char) 0xfec3,
                    (char) 0xfec4, (char) 0xfec1),
            new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xfeda, (char) 0xfedb,
                    (char) 0xfedc, (char) 0xfed9),
            new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xfee2, (char) 0xfee3,
                    (char) 0xfee4, (char) 0xfee1),
            new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xfee6, (char) 0xfee7,
                    (char) 0xfee8, (char) 0xfee5),
            new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xfe96, (char) 0xfe97,
                    (char) 0xfe98, (char) 0xfe95),
            new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d,
                    (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d),
            new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xfede, (char) 0xfedf,
                    (char) 0xfee0, (char) 0xfedd),
            new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xfe90, (char) 0xfe91,
                    (char) 0xfe92, (char) 0xfe8f),
            new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xfef2, (char) 0xfef3,
                    (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfef1),
            new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xfeb2, (char) 0xfeb3,
                    (char) 0xfeb4, (char) 0xfeb1),
            new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xfeb6, (char) 0xfeb7,
                    (char) 0xfeb8, (char) 0xfeb5),
            new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xfec6, (char) 0xfec7,
                    (char) 0xfec8, (char) 0xfec5),
            new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf,
                    (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf),
            new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed,
                    (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed),
            new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xfe94, (char) 0xfe93,
                    (char) 0xfe93, (char) 0xfe93),
            new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef,
                    (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef),
            new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead,
                    (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead),
            new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85,
                    (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85),
            new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80,
                    (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80),
            new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xfe8a, (char) 0xfe8b,
                    (char) 0xfe8c, (char) 0xfe89),
            new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83,
                    (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83),
            new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81,
                    (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81),
            new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87,
                    (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87),
            new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xfb57, (char) 0xfb58,
                    (char) 0xfb59, (char) 0xfb56), // peh
            new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0xfb7b, (char) 0xfb7c,
                    (char) 0xfb7d, (char) 0xfb7a), // cheh
            new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a,
                    (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a), // jeh
            new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xfb8f, (char) 0xfb90,
                    (char) 0xfb91, (char) 0xfb8e), // keheh
            new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xfb93, (char) 0xfb94,
                    (char) 0xfb95, (char) 0xfb92), // gaf
            // new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfbfe,
            // (char) 0xfbff, (char) 0xfbfc), // Farsi yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfef3,
                    (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfbfc), // Arabic yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4,
                    (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4) // heh with yeh
    };

    static struc[] arrStrucWoosim = {
            new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xb5, (char) 0x82, (char) 0xb5,
                    (char) 0x82),
            new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xb4, (char) 0x81, (char) 0xb4,
                    (char) 0x81),
            new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                    (char) 0xbf),
            new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0x9c, (char) 0xb2, (char) 0xfa,
                    (char) 0xc0),
            new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0x9d, (char) 0xb3, (char) 0xfe,
                    (char) 0xc1),
            new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                    (char) 0xd5),
            new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xc9, (char) 0xd3, (char) 0x8b,
                    (char) 0xa4),
            new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xca, (char) 0xdd, (char) 0x8c,
                    (char) 0xa5),
            new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xa6, (char) 0xde, (char) 0x8d,
                    (char) 0xcc),
            new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xa7, (char) 0xdf, (char) 0x8e,
                    (char) 0xce),
            new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                    (char) 0x99),
            new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xc4, (char) 0xc8, (char) 0x87,
                    (char) 0xa0),
            new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xc5, (char) 0xcb, (char) 0x88,
                    (char) 0xa1),
            new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xc6, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                    (char) 0xa2),
            new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8),
            new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xd2, (char) 0xe2, (char) 0x91,
                    (char) 0xaa),
            new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xd4, (char) 0xe3, (char) 0x92,
                    (char) 0xab),
            new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                    (char) 0x99),
            new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xbb, (char) 0x80, (char) 0xbb,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xd1, (char) 0xe1, (char) 0x90,
                    (char) 0xa9),
            new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                    (char) 0x98),
            new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc),
            new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xc2, (char) 0xb8, (char) 0xb8,
                    (char) 0x9e),
            new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xc3, (char) 0xb9, (char) 0xb9,
                    (char) 0x9f),
            new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xc7, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                    (char) 0xc7),
            new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                    (char) 0xb7),
            new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94,
                    (char) 0x94),
            new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda,
                    (char) 0xda),
            new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc),
            new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6,
                    (char) 0xb6),
            new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7,
                    (char) 0xe7),
            new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba,
                    (char) 0xba),
            new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xd7, (char) 0xe8, (char) 0x97,
                    (char) 0xd7),
            new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                    (char) 0x80),
            new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                    (char) 0x98), // peh
            new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                    (char) 0xbf), // cheh
            new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                    (char) 0xb7), // jeh
            new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8), // keheh
            new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                    (char) 0xa8), // gaf
            new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                    (char) 0xdc), // yeh
            new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                    (char) 0xd5) // heh with yeh
    };

    private static final int N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS = 43;

    private static final String ArabicReverse(String s) {
        try {
            String Out = "", rev;
            s = MakeReverse(s);
            char[] chs = new char[s.length()];
            chs = s.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < s.length()) {
                if ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9')) // isDigit(s[i]) ?
                {
                    rev = "";
                    while (i < s.length()
                            && ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9') || chs[i] == '/')) // isDigit(s[i])
                                                                                    // ?
                    {
                        rev = rev + chs[i];
                        ++i;
                    }
                    rev = MakeReverse(rev);
                    Out = Out + rev;
                } else {
                    Out = Out + chs[i];
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            s = Out;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // throw new Exception(
            // "An exception has occurred in ArabicReverse function.\\n"
            // + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static final boolean isFromTheSet1(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
        char[] theSet1 = new char[] { (char) 0x62c, (char) 0x62d, (char) 0x62e,
                (char) 0x647, (char) 0x639, (char) 0x63a, (char) 0x641,
                (char) 0x642, (char) 0x62b, (char) 0x635, (char) 0x636,
                (char) 0x637, (char) 0x643, (char) 0x645, (char) 0x646,
                (char) 0x62a, (char) 0x644, (char) 0x628, (char) 0x64a,
                (char) 0x633, (char) 0x634, (char) 0x638, (char) 0x67e,
                (char) 0x686, (char) 0x6a9, (char) 0x6af, (char) 0x6cc,
                (char) 0x626 };
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 28) {
            if (ch == theSet1[i])
                return true;
            ++i;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static final boolean isFromTheSet2(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
        char[] theSet2 = new char[] { (char) 0x627, (char) 0x623, (char) 0x625,
                (char) 0x622, (char) 0x62f, (char) 0x630, (char) 0x631,
                (char) 0x632, (char) 0x648, (char) 0x624, (char) 0x629,
                (char) 0x649, (char) 0x698, (char) 0x6c0 };
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 14) {
            if (ch == theSet2[i])
                return true;
            ++i;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static final String MakeReverse(String text) {
        String Result = "";
        char[] Ctext = new char[text.length()];
        Ctext = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = (text.length()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Result += Ctext[i];
        }
        return Result;
    }

    public static final String ConvertBackToRealFarsi(String In) {

        if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
            return In;
        }

        String strOut = "";
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
        chIn = In.toCharArray();

        for (i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (j = 0; j < arrStruc.length; j++) {
                if (chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].midGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].iniGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].endGlyph ||
                        chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].isoGlyph) {
                    strBuilder.append(arrStruc[j].character);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                strBuilder.append(chIn[i]);
        }

        strOut = strBuilder.toString();
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLa, "لا");
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLaStick, "لا");

        return strOut;
    }

    public static final String Convert(String In) {

        if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
            return In;
        }

        if (In == null) {
            return "";
        }

        boolean linkBefore, linkAfter;
        String Out = In;
        char[] chOut = new char[Out.length()];
        chOut = Out.toCharArray();
        char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
        chIn = In.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
            /* WCHAR */
            char ch = chIn[i];
            if ((ch >= (char) 0x0621 && ch <= (char) 0x064a)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x067e) || (ch == (char) 0x0686)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x0698) || (ch == (char) 0x06a9)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06af) || (ch == (char) 0x06cc)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06c0)) // is a Farsi character?
            {
                int idx = 0;
                while (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (arrStruc[idx].character == chIn[i])
                        break;
                    ++idx;
                }

                if (i == In.length() - 1)
                    linkAfter = false;
                else
                    linkAfter = (isFromTheSet1(chIn[i + 1]) || isFromTheSet2(chIn[i + 1]));
                if (i == 0)
                    linkBefore = false;
                else
                    linkBefore = isFromTheSet1(chIn[i - 1]);
                if (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].midGlyph;
                    if (linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].endGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].iniGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].isoGlyph;
                } else {
                    chOut[i] = chIn[i];
                }
            } else {
                chOut[i] = chIn[i];
            }
        }
        Out = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < chOut.length; j++)
            Out += chOut[j];
        // Out = ArabicReverse(Out);

        Out = Out.replace((char) 0x200c, ' '); // Change NO SPACE to SPACE

        Out = Out.replace(szLamAndAlef, szLa); // Join 'Lam' and 'Alef' and
                                                // make 'La'
        Out = Out.replace(szLamStickAndAlef, szLaStick); // Join 'Lam Stick'
                                                            // and 'Alef'
                                                            // and make 'La
                                                            // Stick'

        return reorderWords(Out);

    }

    private final static String reorderWords(String strIn)
    {

        final int ST_RTL = 0;
        final int ST_LTR = 1;

        String strOut = "";
        String prevWord = "";
        int state = ST_RTL;
        char[] arr = strIn.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (charIsLTR(arr[i]) && state != ST_LTR)
            {
                // state changed to LTR
                state = ST_LTR;
                strOut = prevWord + strOut;
                prevWord = "";
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            else if (charIsRTL(arr[i]) && state != ST_RTL)
            {
                // state changed to RTL
                state = ST_RTL;
                strOut = prevWord + strOut;
                prevWord = "";
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                // state is not changed
                prevWord += arr[i];
            }
            i++;
        }

        strOut = prevWord + strOut;

        return strOut;

    }

    private final static boolean charIsLTR(char ch)
    {
        return (ch >= (char) 65 & ch <= (char) 122)
                |
                Character.isDigit(ch);
    }

    private final static boolean charIsRTL(char ch)
    {
        return ch >= (char) 0x0621;
    }   

    private static Typeface typeface;

    public static final Typeface GetFarsiFont(Context context) {
        if (typeface == null) {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    // "DroidSansFallback.ttf");
                    "TAHOMA.TTF");
        }
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

> 3) And in your Activity:

```
Typeface tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(this);
MyTextView.setTypeface(tf);
MyTextView.setText(Farsi.Convert("سلام"));
```

You'd just need to replace the code relating to arabic to Persian.