# Android Programming Does not support Farsi Language

Tags: android, fonts, farsi

I am trying to write a new Android program in Farsi language, but charachters just have shown separately in XML file and when I run the emulator the characters have shown separately! Plaese give me step by step procedure to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the min sdk version ?

Comment: Android 2.3.3 version.

Comment: did you test on real phone? because i don't have a problem with that , what is your sdk version ? did you update that ?

Comment: Android sdk 22.2.1. But when I changed the revision of Android to Android 4.1 version,the problem did not solve.

Comment: Amin I think problem is your sdk , i write my application with persian language, in past i have same problem but for now i don't, try run your application in real device, if you had problem in that tell us

Comment: Where can I find the new version of SDK? Thanks a lot for your care.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813, you can update your sdk from sdk manager, but after updating that you need update ADT too, you can update that from help , instal new software from eclipse, or update your android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to the encoding . Check this out : https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/