# Arabic text displayed as ??? in Android

Tags: java, android, encoding, arabic

I am trying to display Arabic text in an Android application, however the Arabic text is displayed as ???.

it works fine when i set the text of a `TextField` directly from xml file using `android:text="مثل"`, but when i try to set it from Java code `mTextView.setText("مثل");`, it displays as question marks character (???).

According to this answer [How to support Arabic text in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android), Arabic is supported for Android 3.x and above.

Comment: make sure your java files are saved in UTF-8 encoding. Not sure about arabic, but cyrrillic fonts are displayed properly

Comment: @injecteer do you mean i should manually change the encoding (save as) of the java files to UTF-8 ?

Comment: yepp, your IDE must be using some other encoding by default.

Comment: @injecteer Well Marcin Orlowski's answer solved the problem. But one should note that it only takes effect after recreating the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `android:text` works fine and setting from code does not, then most likely your source files (*.java) are not using UTF-8 encoding. You need to check your editor/IDE settings - for Android Studio go to `Settings` -> `Editors` -> `File Encodings` and check files and project encoding.

Comment: Changing the Encoding of the IDE doesn't automatically change the encoding of the files. Deleting and recreating the file after setting the proper encoding in the editor solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Just a note, the IDE encoding was set to UTF-8, but the project encoding was set to a different one.

Comment: Good note. I added to the answer for consistency.