# Can't type Farsi text on Android edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I trying to type Persion text on Android edit text but nothing showed on edit text but it works in English. I am using Genymotion virtual device.

This is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
  android:textDirection="rtl"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
    android:hint="نام ..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check your phone is supporting this or not? and is there any exception when you run the project? And you have write something in hint which is showing in the screen or not?

Comment: Yah the hint is showing

Comment: Please refer this url that might help you to achieve your goal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the "language and input settings" in your virtual device.

If this is the problem you have to go to `Settings > Language & Input`; under the `keyboard and input methods` select `Default` and click `set up input methods`. There, you can add several input languages into the keyboard of the Virtual Devices (and also set one as the default language).

Note: the path may differ from device to device.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `set up input methods` settings in your `VD` and add *any language* you need...