# Android Copy paste menu is in Hebrew instead of Arabic

Tags: android, localization, android-edittext

My application supports many languages and whenever I switch to some language and I long click an EditText in my application , I get the menu in the language I'm currently at except in Arabic where I always get the copy paste in Hebrew, i.e I long clicked an EditText and I get "הדבק" instead of "لصق". I searched in Google and I didn't' find anything about it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3529/Arabic-Support-for-Windows-CE 

with explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813

Comment: the copy paste menu when long-clicking the EditText is a system menu whereas the solution you were referring revolves around setting the text in the EditText for which I don't have problem with.