# How to correctly show Arabic letters in Android?

Tags: android, textview, arabic

My application shows letters and words on arabic language. But these letters looks wrong. For example symbols بَ and شَ :

**Correct** (from iOS):

[image: Correct]

**Wrong** (from Android):

[image: Wrong]

As you can see, the little line on the top of letters must be centered. But it's not. How to show Arabic symbols on Android like on iOS?

UPDATE: I am trying to use Better-Arabic-Shapper, but it's also displaying incorrectly:

**Better-Arabic-Shapper**

[image: Better-Arabic-Shapper]

I am trying to set custom fonts (Arial, Simpo, nassim_latn_rg) with the code below but it also doesn't work correctly:

```
private const val FONT_PATH = "fonts/"

val font = "nassim_latn_rg.otf"
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, FONT_PATH + font)
textView.typeface = typeface
```

Comment: Did you add `android:supportsRtl=true` to your Manifest to `<application>` tag? It seems that just the order is wrong

Comment: I update my question. The issue is in the little line on the top of letters must be centered. But it not.

Comment: I had faced the same problem, In my case, there was a problem in the font file (.ttf or .otf file), try to change it, Hope it helps!

Comment: What is your device model?

Comment: Please mention both device name and API version.

Comment: did you try to change font?

Answer (score 3):

I tried with Roboto font, it works fine. All app settings are default. I did not have to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my manifest.

```
<style name="RobotoRegular">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Result:

[image]

Please try this font and revert if you still encounter the issue. I have a feeling this is a font-related issue.

Comment: can you pls add in this comment section your textview's layout attributes

Comment: how are you building your arabic strings?

Comment: could you please let us know witch device you are using and it's android version?

Comment: are you asking me or asking @BArtWell?

Answer (score 0):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file under **application** tag put

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

to allow arabic language. If it doesn't works you need to set **gravity** on the TextView/other views according to the requirement.

**EDIT**

Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079072/4079010) to reshape your arabic language.They used [Better-Arabic-Shapper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/commits/master) for the solution

**EDIT 2**

I just tested this on My Redmi device and it is showing like iOS.

[image: Tested version]

test_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="بَ"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="شَ"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:** Even on the PIXEL emulator using API 28 it is showing fine. check the image below:

[image: Pixel emulator]

Comment: I update my question. Little line on the top of letters must be centered. But it not.How to fix it?

Comment: No, it also works wrong. Please look updated answer.

Comment: Did you try adding font to the text? Which font is suitable for arabic?

Comment: Yes, I am tryung to use Arial, nassim_latn_rg and Simpo, but it doesn't help. Simpo successfully used on iOS.

Comment: if you used the same font in both OS versions(iOS and Android) then the result should be same. Can you show me how you have applied font to the text?

Comment: On the above comments you declared that in iOS 'Simpo' was successfully used but in Android (from edited code) you are using 'nassim_latn_rg'

Comment: you should same on both side

Comment: Yes, but Simpo also not works correctly. I am checked it again right now.

Comment: No, it also doesn't works correctly. Not same like nassim_latn_rg, but not correctly.

Comment: No, it nothing changing.

Comment: With Farsi it works if string contains only arabic letters. If string contains arabic letters and english letter it also works incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, because the font is applied for arabic only. If you want to use both go for String Builder.

Comment: If the issue still persist share me the link of TTF font file. So, i can get better review

Comment: on the sample from Better-Arabic-Reshaper, they are using  DejaVuSans.ttf